# Find nodes (n) with :OWNER relations to nodes (a), (b), and (c) and no other nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My Neo4j 3.2 database has nodes `(n)` which may have `:OWNER` relations to other nodes. I want to find all the nodes `(n)` with `:OWNER` relations specifically to nodes `(a)`, `(b)`, and `(c)` and specifically not to any other nodes.

I would have thought that this would be fairly easily accomplished with

```
MATCH (n), (o)
WHERE (
  (n)-[:OWNER]->(o) AND o.uuid IN $owner_ids
  AND NOT ((n)-[:OWNER]->(o) AND NOT o.uuid IN $owner_ids)
RETURN (n)
```

But it doesn't work. This query incorrectly returns nodes `(n)` with `:OWNER` relations to `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`, *and* `(d)`. I've also tried

```
MATCH (n), (o)
WHERE (n)-[:OWNER]->(o) AND o.uuid IN $owner_ids
WITH (n),(o)
WHERE NOT ((n)-[:OWNER]->(o) AND NOT o.uuid IN $owner_ids)
RETURN (n)
```

As well as what feels like a million other permutations to no avail. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

#### UPDATE

The above is a simplified scenario. As requested in a comment, an example closer to reality is:

```
MATCH (a)<-[:ANSWER]-(:Person {uuid: $person_id}), (o)
WHERE (exists((o)<-[:OWNER]-(:Owner)<-[:OWNER]-(:Form)-[:ANSWER]->(a)) AND o.uuid IN $owner_ids)
      AND NOT (exists((o)<-[:OWNER]-(:Owner)<-[:OWNER]-(:Form)-[:ANSWER]->(a)) AND NOT o.uuid IN $owner_ids)
RETURN (a)
```

## ANSWER

The full answer is

```
MATCH (o)<-[:OWNER]-(:Owner)<-[:OWNER]-(:Form)-[:ANSWER]->(a)<-[:ANSWER]-(:Person {uuid: $person_id})
WHERE o.uuid IN $owner_ids
WITH (a), count(o) as cnt
WHERE cnt = size(()<-[:OWNER]-(:Owner)<-[:OWNER]-(:Form)-[:ANSWER]->(a))
RETURN (a)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using labels in your graph, which will greatly slow your queries (since all nodes of the graph will need to be scanned per match to a node), and you can't use indexes without labels. Please add labels to your graph and update your description.

Comment: @InverseFalcon, I distilled my problem down to what I think is the core issue before posting. I've updated my question with a query much closer to the true one, however.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start to update my answer. Watch out for that cartesian product with `o` in your MATCH, and make sure to EXPLAIN (or PROFILE) the query to see the query plan.

Comment: It looks like your graph has :Owners of things (like :Forms), but :Owners also have :Owners? Is that correct?

Comment: @InverseFalcon, the actual `(:Owner)` node is used because relations cannot, themselves, have relations or multiple labels. The `(:Owner)` node is actually part of the relation. The `(o)` node is the owner, and it is polymorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you add labels to your graph (let's use :Node for now, though it's not clear from your description if all nodes should be the same or if some should use different labels), and that you have a unique constraint on :Node(uuid) for quick lookup, this should work:

```
MATCH (n:Node)-[:OWNER]->(o:Node)
WHERE o.uuid IN $owner_ids
WITH n, count(o) as cnt
WHERE cnt = size((n)-[:OWNER]->())
RETURN n
```

Your query had a cartesian product between `n` and `o` (the cross product of all the nodes of your graph with each other), which [won't perform well](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/cross-product-cypher-queries-will-not-perform-well/). You need to specify the relationship in the MATCH, not the WHERE.

As for the rest of the query, we're getting, for each `n`, the count of `o` nodes (those with the ids in question), and ensuring that the number of :OWNER relationships for each `n` is equal to that count. If it's greater, then there are :OWNER relationships to other nodes, so those are filtered out.

The `size()` function we're using, since we aren't specifying anything for the end node, is [efficient at getting relationship counts](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-counting-number-of-relationships-on-a-node/).

Comment: GENIOUS!!! Thank you so much!! I think I've been working on this problem for 2 hours now. Such a good solution! Just tested and it absolutely works!

Comment: Great! looks like I won't have to modify the answer after all. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement was to have all three :OWNER relationships present (not just any subset of them), then I'd use this query:

```
  WITH ['a', 'b', 'c'] AS ids
 MATCH (n:Node)-[:OWNER]->(o:Node)
  WITH n,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN o.uuid IN ids THEN 1 END) AS matches_found,
       size(ids) AS matches_desired,
       count(o)  AS total_relationships
 WHERE matches_found = matches_desired
   AND matches_found = total_relationships
RETURN n
 ORDER BY n.uuid
```